# How to create new file and open in Google Docs editor?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Is it possible to create a new Google Docs document, and then open it in the Google Docs editor? We have documents in our site that would be great to upload to Google Docs for editing but I'm having trouble figuring out if that's possible between the deprecated docs list API, and the new Google Drive API. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

When you upload a file you will get back an item resource which contains a field AlternateLink. This is the edit URL.

To try it, go to https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it, click Oauth to On, then paste one of your file IDs into the fileId field. When you get back the item resource, just click the AlternateLink